# Passing an argument from ruby to a python scripts

Tags: python, ruby

I have a problem that I hope you guys can help me out with.
Im making a home automation system with RPi + Piface to control devices on the network.

```
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                           LIGHTS Automation
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  room=0

  listen_for /Turn on kitchen lights/i do
    lights('kitchen')
    request_completed
  end

  def lights(varible)
     IO.popen("python /root/SiriProxy/plugins/siriproxy-teamsiri/TeamsiriPython/test.py varible")
  end
```

this is my line of code. Im calling a python script and it works fine but I want use functions
"varible"will be the varible to pass to the script but it does not send it as a varible but a string.
Any one got some good ideas how to solve it

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
IO.popen("python /root/SiriProxy/plugins/siriproxy-teamsiri/TeamsiriPython/test.py varible")
```

to

```
IO.popen("python /root/SiriProxy/plugins/siriproxy-teamsiri/TeamsiriPython/test.py #{variable}")
```

and the variable value will be substituted into the string.

Note that this only works inside double-quoted strings.